# highlight the image icon when clicked on it

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I Have 3 Images as `icons` for different use.

Now what I want is,

> If the first icon is clicked, the first icon should be `highlighted`, if second is clicked the second icon should be `highlighted`.

Please see the HTML for your ref:-

```
<tr>
        <td width="18%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;" width="6%">
            <input type="checkbox" id="branchChkbx" title="Branch" checked="checked" class="hideChkbx" />
            <a href="locateBranches_rbl_view.aspx" style="color: #666; font-family: 'signika_negativeRegular', sans-serif;">
                <img alt="Branch" src="images/branch_icon.png" height="40" width="40" title="Branch" style="border: 0;" />
                <p class="para01">Branch</p>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;" width="5%">
            <input type="checkbox" id="atmChkbx" title="ATM" checked="checked" class="hideChkbx" />
            <a href="locateATM_rbl.aspx" style="color: #666; font-family: 'signika_negativeRegular', sans-serif;">
                <img alt="ATM" src="images/atm_icon.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATM" style="border: 0;" /><p class="para01">ATM</p>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;" width="6%">
            <input type="checkbox" id="lockerChkbx" title="Locker" checked="checked" class="hideChkbx" />
            <a href="locateLockers_rbl.aspx" style="color: #666; font-family: 'signika_negativeRegular', sans-serif;">
                <img alt="Locker" src="images/locker_icon.png" height="40" width="40" title="Locker" style="border: 0;" /><p class="para01">Locker</p>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td width="6%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" style="border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;">
            <a id="A1" href="Default.aspx" runat="server" style="float: left; text-decoration: underline; color: #666; margin-left: 12px; font-family: 'signika_negativeRegular', sans-serif;">
                <p class="para01">View All</p>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Also see the CSS:-

```
.para01 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it like this

**CSS**

```
para01 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        /*line-height: 1.5em;*/
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .highlight {
        background: yellow;
    }
    .imghighlight{
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
    }
```

JQuery:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input.hideChkbx').on('change', function () {
            $('input.hideChkbx').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            $('input.hideChkbx').not(this).parent().find("img").removeClass("imghighlight");
            $('input.hideChkbx').not(this).parent().find(".para01").removeClass("highlight");
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parent().find("img").addClass("imghighlight");
                $(this).parent().find(".para01").addClass("highlight");
            }
        });
    });
```

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your best option should be to make the images into css sprite, and change background-sizes. If that's hard for you, you can just make images background of the A tag. Like so:

```
a {
   background: url('image.png') no-repeat center center;
}
a.highlighted {
   background-image: url('image-highlight.png');
}
```

Comment: I just gave you the best practice of doing such things. You did it with too much work around. Also your question was not properly asked, you did not even mention anything about the checkboxes.

Anyway im glad you made it work :)

Comment: Sorry if you felt bad, but your way was something i had to make sprite images and all. But I just did with 2,3 css attributes